# Unable to select rows of UITableView in UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have created an app using a `storyboard`. In other screens, I have used a `UITableViewController` directly  and the selection is working as expected.

In this case, I have a `UITableView` that is one of several controls within a `UIViewController`.

My custom ViewController.h file has a definition similar to the below:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
    @property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;
@end
```

Then within `viewDidLoad` I am doing this:

```
_myTableView.delegate = self;
_myTableView.dataSource = self;
```

Having done this, my `numberOfSectionsInTableView`, `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` methods are all being called and my table looks as I want it to.

The problem I have is that the rows do not select and the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method is not getting called.

I have checked that Selection is set to Single Selection in the storyboard view and I have also tried to set `_myTableView.allowsSelection=YES;` in `viewDidLoad` but this doesn't seem to make any difference.

I know that this is probably something to do with the fact that my table is within a normal view controller, but I can't figure out the magic step I've missed to make the selection work.

For now I have added a workaround. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I have attached a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to each view in the cell:

```
for(UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews){
    [view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapRow:)];
    [tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    view.tag = row; // So that I can identify in the handler which row has been tapped
}
```

Then in the handler:

```
-(void)tapRow:(id)sender{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *gesture = (UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender;
    UIView *myView = (UIView*)gesture.view;
    int row = myView.tag;
    // Handle tap of row here
}
```

This achieves what I need, but I would still like to figure out what I've done wrong with the row selection!

Comment: Are you sure of your implementation of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` ? Did you check that you did not implement `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` instead ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately that's not the case for me. As well as the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function not being called I am also not getting the default grey selection of the rows when I tap on them

Comment: Have you added UI elements to the cell, or are you using a standard cell? Assuming that the delegate is properly set, the main reason for the problem you're seeing is something else is either intercepting the touches, or you have an element like a image view that has its userInteractionEnabled property set to NO. Your problem has nothing to do with the table being in a UIViewController.

Comment: Are you using cell.selectionStyle property some where.

Comment: @rdelmar, there is a single label in the cell. I have tried reducing the size of this so that I can touch the 'bare cell' but it still doesn't select. The UILabel, it's containing UIView and the Cell all have User Interaction Enabled. I've actually implemented a work around for now which I'll edit into the question, but I can't see what's stopping the standard selection.

Comment: I can't see anything you're doing wrong. You shouldn't have to add a gesture recognizer, and you shouldn't have to decrease the size of the label (since a label doesn't handle the touch, it's passed through to the cell). If you could post your project somewhere, I'll look at it, but otherwise I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure there is not another view on top of the table view (e.g. a transparent view that would be stealing touch events).  Also ensure that userInteraction is enabled for the tableview and all of its parent views.

Comment: Thanks Brian, I don't think that's the issue for me as I can scroll the table without any issues, so it is seeing those gestures

Answer (score 1):

We type sometime wrong delegate call didDeselectRowAtIndexPath  instead of didSeselectRowAtIndexPath. Is it your case?

I see that you can update your content in the tableview so the connection should be OK. I think about mistakes with function names.

Just to test: Replace your didSelectRowAtIndexPath function with this (copy, paste).

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"Selected %d",indexPath.row);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately that's not the case for me. As well as the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function not being called I am also not getting the default grey selection of the rows when I tap on them

Comment: Try also to set selection type = Blue or Default (not NONE) then test if your tableview change color when you select a row or not.

Comment: Thank you, still same results I'm afraid

Answer (score 1):

Just incase anyone still has this problem. I just realised `-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method won't work for any view or subview with a tap gesture recogniser set to it. So remove the tap gesture recogniser from that view of it's parent view. if you still want to handle touch events, then use "touchesBegan" function. ` - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {
 [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

}`

Answer (score 0):

I had the exactly the same problem with my current project for two minutes yesterday when I realised that I didn't link my delegate and dataSource of the table view. You made it programmatically, so it should work. For me was a delegation problem, you can check your Attributes Inspector to make sure that everything is ok.

Answer (score -2):

In cellForRowAtIndexPath method add this line

cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that doesn't make any difference for me.

Comment: This is wrong. The userInteractionEnabled has to be YES for cell selection to work (which it is by default).